# Javascript loop - waiting on value

Tags: javascript

Having a nightmare with a function that's finishing before all the code has run. Am trying to build in a counter, and only returning when the code is finished.

I've emulated this like so (I know it's not fantastic, but if someone could point me along the right lines, I'd be very grateful):

```
//I want this to alert "Done"
alert(timerCheck());

function timerCheck() {
    var finished;
    var myLoop = 5;
    for (i = 0; i < myLoop; i++) {
        //This is emulating the slow code
        window.setTimeout(checkFinished, 900);
        alert(i);
    }
    function checkFinished() {
        //I originally had the "return here, before realising my error
        finished = true;
    }
    if (finished) {
        //This is where my problem is 
        return "done";
    }
}
```

Like I said, a much simplified example - if someone could point out the mistake, it'd save me a lot of hassle!

Comment: You cannot get the return value of a function synchronously if that function calls and depends on asynchronous functions. You have to work with callbacks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070275/javascript-closures-and-callbacks

Comment: if you have access to jquery, you can use deferred and promise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009194/how-to-use-jquery-deferred-with-custom-events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get the return value of a function synchronously if that function calls and depends on asynchronous functions.

You have to work with callbacks. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070275/javascript-closures-and-callbacks) for some more details.

For example, your function would look like this:

```
// pass a callback which gets the result of function
timerCheck(function(result) {
    alert(result);
});

function timerCheck(callback) {
    var myLoop = 5,
        j = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < myLoop; i++) {
        // This is emulating the slow code
        // this will invoke `checkFinished` immediately, 
        // after 900ms, after 1800ms, after 2700ms and after 3600ms
        window.setTimeout(checkFinished, i * 900);
    }

    function checkFinished() {
       j++;
       // after checkFinish was called 5 times, we invoke the callback
       if(j === 5) {
           callback('done');
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As FelixKling commented, *you cannot get the return value of a function synchronously if that function calls and depends on asynchronous functions*. One solution of those kind of jobs could be:

```
var finished = false;

function mySlowCode() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        finished = true;
    }, 1000);
}

function timerCheck() {
    // legend...
    (function waitForIt() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!finished) {
                waitForIt();
            } else {
                // dary!
                letsDoIt();
            }
        }, 10);
    })();
}

function letsDoIt() {
    alert("done");
}

mySlowCode();
timerCheck();
```

The function `timerCheck()` will call the function `letsDoIt()` once the function `mySlowCode()` is finished.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried it with no parens after function name?

```
alert(timerCheck);
```

Comment: This would just alert the function's body, not invoke the function.